# Regex between word and end of text

Tags: sql, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to break up SQL queries into smaller, sub-queries. Given a query like this:

```
create unlogged table A 
AS 
SELECT significant_digits(round(SUM(value * avgweight)/SUM(avgweight)), 2) AS avgvalue, 
       significant_digits(sum(value),2) AS sumvalue, 
       R_state AS F_state, 
       NULL AS F_year, 
       R_county AS F_county, 
       R_candidate AS F_candidate 
FROM R0 
WHERE TRUE 
  AND R_candidate IS NOT NULL 
  AND R_county IS NOT NULL 
  AND R_state IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY R_candidate, R_county, R_state 
UNION ALL 
SELECT significant_digits(round(SUM(value * avgweight)/SUM(avgweight)), 2) AS avgvalue, 
       significant_digits(sum(value),2) AS sumvalue, 
       NULL AS F_state, 
       NULL AS F_year, 
       NULL AS F_county, 
       R_candidate AS F_candidate 
FROM R0 
WHERE TRUE 
  AND R_candidate IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY R_candidate
```

I want to be able to extract each of the SELECT statements from this query. I wrote a basic Regex for getting text between SELECT and UNION, but I'm struggling with how I can get the text between SELECT and the end of the query.

`"SELECT(.*?)UNION"`

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt there's a RegEx for it. What if you got nested Selects like Derived Table or Common Table Expression or Scalar Subqueries?

Comment: I agree that it wouldn't be possible to generalize, but all of the queries are structured in that exact same format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(SELECT(.*?)UNION)|(SELECT.*)`

This works as I intended